# Here-API - Getroute historical route data

Tags: here-api

I have searched the questions here and gone through a fair amount of the API. I have not found reference to requesting historic route data. My questions is this; Does the Here api support historical route data. An example request would be that I seek the mileage from point a to point b 365 days ago, when perhaps a key route obstruction existed such as a bridge was out or a road was closed for construction that resulted in more miles during that historic period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to answer this in two parts

1. Can a route be calculated for a past date ?
   Yes, you can. You need to request a Time Aware Route like below. You can read      more about it in the developer site.

`

```
GET https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json
    ?app_id={YOUR_APP_ID} 
    &app_code={YOUR_APP_CODE} 
    &mode=fastest;car;
    &waypoint0=geo!37.743385,-122.422835
    &waypoint1=geo!37.743878,-122.423686
    &departure=2014-03-12T10:00:00
    &routeattributes=sh,bb,g
```

`

2. Will the map used for the query depend on the departure date ?
   No, Here API always uses the current version of the map available unless you specify explicitly the map version. But you can specify only till previous two releases.

So for your question, you wont be able to get the map data for a past year even using map version. But what you can do, is explicitly avoid the bridge or road newly constructed so that the api doesn't suggest that route. You can do this through Custom Route Extension API like below example.

```
GET http://cre.api.here.com/2/overlays/upload.json
      ?map_name=OVERLAYBLOCKROAD
      &overlay_spec=[{"op":"override","shape":[[50.10765,8.68774],[50.10914,8.68771]],"layer":"LINK_ATTRIBUTE_FCN","data":{"VEHICLE_TYPES":"0"}}]
      &storage=readonly
      &app_id={YOUR_APP_ID} 
      &app_code={YOUR_APP_CODE}
```